# Finding the maximum cycle of a given set

Tags: combinatorics, periodic-functions, pattern-recognition

**Problem:** Given $4$ circles, we define the following set of rules:

**i)** Any circle which contains $\ge 3 $ elements transfers exactly one of its elements to each of other $3$ circles.

**ii)** Circles which contain $<3$ number of element do not transfer any of its elements to the other three circles.

In one operation all rules are applied simultaneously.

There are two states which can be achieved under these rules:

[image] [image][image]

This is a **stable** state reached.

[image]
[image]

This is an **oscillating** state.

**Question:** I am curious to find what is the maximum value of $k$ such that some initial configuration cycles through $k$ distinct configurations and returns to the original configuration (for the first time) after $k$ operations? $k$ is also called the least period of the transformation.

Comment: 1/ The case where all values are $ \geq 3$ has period 1. 2/ Any initial configuration that results in a cycle where all values are $ \geq 3$ has eventual period 1, so can be ignored. This happens if the sum is greater than 100 (and possibly  even 18). 3/ So you can check the finitely many cases that remain.

Comment: You should have mentioned that you had asked [this more extended question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620079) about this problem and deleted it after it was closed. The reason for the closure is relevant here, too: "Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc."

Comment: So the two rules are applied simultaneously to all the circles? The oscillation from 4422 to 2244 is one step, not 4422 to 1533 to 2244 or something else where you deal with one at a time?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_sandpile_model

Answer (score 1):

To fix the setup, label four circles as circle 1, circle 2, circle 3 and circle 4. Use an array of four numbers $A(t)=(A_1(t),A_2(t),A_3(t),A_4(t))$ to denote configuration at a particular instant $t$, where $A_i(t)$ is the number of elements in circle $i$ respectively. For brevity, $t$ might be omitted. $\min(A)$ means the smallest number among all $A_i$. $\max(A)$ means the biggest number among all $A_i$.

##### Some lemmas

**Lemma**: if $\min(A)\ge3$, $A$ is a stable state.
Proof: In one operation, $A_1$ decreases by 3 as it transfers 3 to other numbers and increases by 3 as it receives 1 from each of the 3 other numbers. Hence $A_1$ will stay the same. By symmetry, so will $A_2,A_3,A_4$.

**Lemma**: if $\max(A)<3$, $A$ is a stable state.
Proof: There will not be any transfer.

**Lemma**: If $\max(A)$ is $\le5$, then so will it be always.
Proof: In one operation,

- if $A_1\le2$, $A_1$ can increase by at most $3$.
- else $A_1\ge3$, $A_1$ will not increase.

Hence $A_1$ will become at most $5$ in one operation. So will $A_2,A_3,A_4$.

**Lemma**: If $\min(A)<3$ and $\max(A)\ge6$, then $\max(A)$ becomes smaller in one operation.
Proof:  In one operation,

- if $A_1\le2$, $A_1$ can increase by at most $3$. So $A_1$ will be at most $5$.
- else $A_1\ge3$, $A_1$ will decrease at least by $1$ since the minimum number in $A$ will not transfer $1$ to it.

In all cases, $A_1$ will become one less than the current $\max(A)$. So will $A_2,A_3,A_4$.

**Lemma**: If $A$ is an oscillating state, then $\min(A)<3$ and $3\le\max(A)\le5$.
Proof: This is implied by the previous three lemmas.

##### Check 96 tuples

The last lemma above tells that we need just to check 96 states below, where $\min(A)<3$ and $3\le\max(A)\le5$, $A_1\le A_2\le A_3\le A_4$.

$(0, 0, 0, 3)$, $(0, 0, 0, 4)$, $(0, 0, 0, 5)$, $(0, 0, 1, 3)$,
$(0, 0, 1, 4)$, $(0, 0, 1, 5)$, $(0, 0, 2, 3)$, $(0, 0, 2, 4)$,
$(0, 0, 2, 5)$, $(0, 0, 3, 3)$, $(0, 0, 3, 4)$, $(0, 0, 3, 5)$,
$(0, 0, 4, 4)$, $(0, 0, 4, 5)$, $(0, 0, 5, 5)$, $(0, 1, 1, 3)$,
$(0, 1, 1, 4)$, $(0, 1, 1, 5)$, $(0, 1, 2, 3)$, $(0, 1, 2, 4)$,
$(0, 1, 2, 5)$, $(0, 1, 3, 3)$, $(0, 1, 3, 4)$, $(0, 1, 3, 5)$,
$(0, 1, 4, 4)$, $(0, 1, 4, 5)$, $(0, 1, 5, 5)$, $(0, 2, 2, 3)$,
$(0, 2, 2, 4)$, $(0, 2, 2, 5)$, $(0, 2, 3, 3)$, $(0, 2, 3, 4)$,
$(0, 2, 3, 5)$, $(0, 2, 4, 4)$, $(0, 2, 4, 5)$, $(0, 2, 5, 5)$,
$(0, 3, 3, 3)$, $(0, 3, 3, 4)$, $(0, 3, 3, 5)$, $(0, 3, 4, 4)$,
$(0, 3, 4, 5)$, $(0, 3, 5, 5)$, $(0, 4, 4, 4)$, $(0, 4, 4, 5)$,
$(0, 4, 5, 5)$, $(0, 5, 5, 5)$, $(1, 1, 1, 3)$, $(1, 1, 1, 4)$,
$(1, 1, 1, 5)$, $(1, 1, 2, 3)$, $(1, 1, 2, 4)$, $(1, 1, 2, 5)$,
$(1, 1, 3, 3)$, $(1, 1, 3, 4)$, $(1, 1, 3, 5)$, $(1, 1, 4, 4)$,
$(1, 1, 4, 5)$, $(1, 1, 5, 5)$, $(1, 2, 2, 3)$, $(1, 2, 2, 4)$,
$(1, 2, 2, 5)$, $(1, 2, 3, 3)$, $(1, 2, 3, 4)$, $(1, 2, 3, 5)$,
$(1, 2, 4, 4)$, $(1, 2, 4, 5)$, $(1, 2, 5, 5)$, $(1, 3, 3, 3)$,
$(1, 3, 3, 4)$, $(1, 3, 3, 5)$, $(1, 3, 4, 4)$, $(1, 3, 4, 5)$,
$(1, 3, 5, 5)$, $(1, 4, 4, 4)$, $(1, 4, 4, 5)$, $(1, 4, 5, 5)$,
$(1, 5, 5, 5)$, $(2, 2, 2, 3)$, $(2, 2, 2, 4)$, $(2, 2, 2, 5)$,
$(2, 2, 3, 3)$, $(2, 2, 3, 4)$, $(2, 2, 3, 5)$, $(2, 2, 4, 4)$,
$(2, 2, 4, 5)$, $(2, 2, 5, 5)$, $(2, 3, 3, 3)$, $(2, 3, 3, 4)$,
$(2, 3, 3, 5)$, $(2, 3, 4, 4)$, $(2, 3, 4, 5)$, $(2, 3, 5, 5)$,
$(2, 4, 4, 4)$, $(2, 4, 4, 5)$, $(2, 4, 5, 5)$, $(2, 5, 5, 5)$.

Using brute force by hand or by programming, we can find the maximum least period is $4$, which comes from the following two cases.
$$(2, 3, 4, 5) \to  (5, 2, 3, 4) \to  (4, 5, 2, 3)
  \to  (3, 4, 5, 2) \to  (2, 3, 4, 5)\to\cdots $$
$$ (0, 1, 2, 3) \to  (1, 2, 3, 0) \to  (2, 3, 0, 1)
 \to  (3, 0, 1, 2) \to  (0, 1, 2, 3) \to\cdots$$

##### What about more circles?

The problem in the question is about $4$ circles. What about more circles? I wrote a small program to check the case with $n=2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ circles. It turns out the maximum least period is always the same as the number of circles. Furthermore, there are $\phi(n)$ cycles with least period $n$, where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler totient function.

$n=2$
Max period $2$: $(0, 1)$

$n=3$
Max period $3$: $(0, 1, 2)$, $(1, 2, 3)$

$n=4$
Max period $4$: $(0, 1, 2, 3)$, $(2, 3, 4, 5)$

$n=5$
Max period $5$: $(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)$, $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)$, $(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$, $(3, 4, 5, 6, 7)$

$n=6$
Max period $6$: $(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)$, $(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)$,

$n=7$
Max period $7$: $(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)$, $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)$, $(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)$, $(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)$, $(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)$, $(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)$,

$n=8$
Max period $8$: $(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)$, $(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)$, $(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)$, $(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)$,

It is natural to raise the following conjecture.

**Conjecture**. The maximum least period for $n$ numbers in $n$ circles is $n$. There are $\phi(n)$ such cycles.

Comment: After thinking for 3 more hours, I concluded that I need probably 20 hours more to find a proof for the last step to claim 4 is the maximum period for the remaining 96 tuples that is significantly shorter than the brute force, which costs at most 30 minutes by hand or 15 minutes by programming.